# Flag rejeitada pra uma resposta

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, respostas, sinalização

Ontem eu sinalizei esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98174/3635 como:

> **não é uma resposta**
>
> Esta resposta não é uma tentativa concreta de resolver o problema. Seria melhor transformada em comentário, edição, outra pergunta ou excluída.

No entanto ela foi rejeitada e tinha a seguinte mensagem:

> não é uma resposta – Guilherme Nascimento ontem   rejeitado - É sim uma resposta (mesmo se estiver errada)

Eu não sinalizei por ser uma resposta errada, eu sinalizei por não ser uma tentativa concreta de resolver o problema, que se trata de *C#* ou *API* do Windows (no meu entendimento sobre pergunta).

A minha solicitação foi pra converter pra um comentário e não pra excluir, como descrito na sinalização *não é uma resposta* (Seria melhor transformada em comentário, edição, outra pergunta ou excluída).

Comment: Pois eu votei para converter a resposta em comentario, dado que de resposta nada tem, mas pelos vistos continua por la.

Comment: @Omni Obrigado, talvez isto ajude a reforçar.

Comment: Vendo o [histórico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/47358) há um voto "Remover", um "Parece OK"  e quatro "Recomendar exclusão". Não sei qual é a conjugação mínima de votos para que ela seja removida.

Comment: Estranho @ramaral acho que geralmente quando houve rejeição de uma flag é que um usuário ou moderador com poderes que intermediou, o que faz os votos não terem tanta validade (acredito eu), o texto (rejeitado - É sim uma resposta (mesmo se estiver errada)) que recebi de resposta da minha flag não parece ser automático e sim escrito por alguém.

Comment: Eu já tive uma sinalização rejeitada e o texto era este: `rejeitado - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it `. Ela indica explicitamente que foi por um moderador.

Comment: @ramaral sim é bem provável que seja o caso pro meu também. O jeito é esperar alguém se manisfesta :)

Comment: É uma resposta mal elaborada, mas além de responder a pergunta, está correta. Quando você agenda uma tarefa para outro usuário, ela não aparece na sessão do usuário corrente. A flag que cabe é a de "baixa qualidade", o que é um problema completamente diferente. Seria o caso de deixar um comentário sugerindo ao usuário de explicar melhor a solução, e elaborar mais a resposta.

Comment: @Bacco Eu estava pensando sobre isso. Acho que ele responde a uma pergunta mal feita, *mas responde*. Querer um `console application` que ao executar não mostre o `console` me soa um tanto contraditório. A pergunta deveria ser: "Como escondo a execução do meu programa no windows?" - aí a resposta se encaixa perfeitamente.

Comment: @DanielGomes é, eu até pus um **[comentário na pergunta dizendo mais ou menos isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98150/console-application-sem-mostrar-a-janela-do-console/98174#comment199585_98150)**, e sugerindo algumas alternativas. Fazer uma aplicação que não mostre o console é uma coisa. Rodar uma aplicação console escondida, é outra bem diferente. Eu espero que o autor a melhore, pois realmente é de baixa qualidade, mas tem potencial de resolver o problema.

Comment: @Omni onde você _"votou para converter a resposta em comentario"_? Que eu saiba não existe nenhuma UI para isso.

Comment: @Math votei para remover, salvo erro menciona la converter em comentário (preciso de aceder ao UI das publicações de baixa qualidade e confirmar e logo actualizo o comentario).

Comment: @ramaral tb não sei exatamente a proporção, ela fica ainda mais confusa se a resposta tiver um voto positivo, mas acho que para respostas com 0 votos ela pode ser removida com 3 votos de remoção (que podem ser dados por usuários com 20K+), ou 6 votos de (remoção || recomendação de exclusão). É algo assim..

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sua sinalização foi rejeitada por um moderador, mas pelo que eu entendi a resposta voltou para a fila de análises devido a sinalização de outro usuário posterior a sua ter sido rejeitada.

Comment: @Bacco fato curioso: aparentemente as sinalizações de "baixa qualidade" e "não é uma resposta" servem para a mesma coisa, as duas levam a resposta para a fila de análises de baixa qualidade, e as ações possíveis para os usuários é de remover, editar ou manter. Portanto, acredito que o correto seria apenas comentar para o autor da resposta e possivelmente negativar.

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando usar “excluir” ao analisar “Publicações de Baixa Qualidade”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/662/3117)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fui eu que cuidei dessa sinalização. Geralmente, marco as sinalizações como úteis mesmo que eu acabe não fazendo nada com a postagem em questão. São raros os casos em que eu rejeito sinalizações, e na maioria das vezes faço para chamar mais atenção do usuário. Este caso foi um deles – e funcionou, o assunto veio até pro meta :P Como você, Guilherme, é um usuário experiente do site, achei que valia a pena usar esse recurso para dar um toque mais enfático.

O motivo da rejeição já foi citado por outros usuários aqui: aquela resposta se refere precisamente ao que foi perguntado, é uma tentativa de solucionar o problema. Tudo indica que é uma solução eficaz, mas continuaria sendo uma tentativa de solução mesmo que estivesse errada. Eu não considero uma boa resposta, já que poderia ser mais detalhada. Mas também não é uma dica (que justificaria a conversão em comentário), nem algo totalmente sem relação com a pergunta (o que justificaria a remoção).

Comment: Sim, imaginei isto, o motivo da minha flag foi realmente o citado, a tag `c#`, mas como dito por todos, o problema era em como a pergunta foi formulada, não houve especificação por parte do AP e realmente o argumento dele de que só pode ser **console** da a entender que talvez ele nem tenha controle sobre a aplicação (ele não pode recompilar ou não sabe fazer ou o código não é dele) e na verdade ele queria uma solução pra Windows mesmo o que torna a resposta totalmente valida até mais que as outras respostas. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 6):

Quando há uma tentativa de oferecer uma solução, mesmo que extremamente pobre ou até equivocada, **não devemos** votar para deletar ou sinalizar como *Não É Uma Resposta*. E, [em princípio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224449/sanity-check-on-naa-flag/224452#224452), o trabalho dos moderadores não é avaliar se uma resposta é correta tecnicamente.

O caminho indicado é votar negativamente ou fazer um comentário solicitando esclarecimentos (ou ambas coisas).

O mesmo vale para uma resposta do tipo:

> Use `funcaoTal()` como pode ver neste [link](/#).

Só o fato de citar qual função resolve o problema já descaracteriza a resposta como *Somente Link*.

Se já houver abundância de respostas completas e bem explicadas e essa nova resposta pobre não acrescentar nada, então merece vários votos negativos para deixá-la opaca e eventualmente forçar o autor a melhorá-la ou removê-la. E duvido que votos para deletar serão contestados.

Se o caso for mais complicado do que isso, o correto é usar o sinalizador **precisa de atenção dos moderadores** e explicar o problema em detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado brasofilo, eu ia escolher a sua resposta, mas devido a ser mas como o @bfavaretto foi quem atuou nisto previamente então marquei a dele, mas a sua resposta esclarece bem o problema, muito obrigado!